# Chat bot for .net core application

Tags: .net, .net-core, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I want to create a chat bot which will guide users as per their choice.

Which bot framework should be good for .net core web application?

1. Is it possible to integrate a Python chat bot in .net core application? If yes then how?
2. Which are some free bot frameworks I can use to use in my .net core web app?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using .NET, I can see that you're already familiar with Microsoft products. However, there still seems to be some confusion. The **botframework** and **azure-bot-service** tags you've used are not referring to "bot frameworks" in general but rather the [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service) specifically, as can be inferred from the logos attached to them. If you want to build a .NET Core bot then the Microsoft Bot Framework is the way to go. The Microsoft Bot Framework includes the free [Bot Builder SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk) to help you build the bot code, but once you're done running the bot locally and want to actually deploy it there's really no way to host a production bot for free that can reach any significant number of users. There are always going to be server costs involved at minimum.

Since you mention Python, I will tell you that one of the four available Bot Builder languages is [Python](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python), but Python is not a .NET language so it doesn't make any sense to talk about integrating a Python bot in a .NET Core application. However, if you're running both a Python bot and a .NET Core app you can always have them communicate with each other using HTTP as when using a REST API.

Comment: I agree on what you said for Python. But i read somewhere about python for .net and I thought this could be useful for my app.  I will obviously look for Microsoft Bot framework though as you suggested.
Also as you mention in last "have them communicate with each other using HTTP", can you please provide me a link for like documentation on the same?

Comment: You can learn about HTTP and REST API's on many sites like [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/). Since I've answered the question you posted, you should upvote and accept this answer. If you have more questions then you should post a new question. I recommend reading about the subjects you're interested in until you know enough to ask one specific question about what you've already decided you want to do. This question was downvoted because Stack Overflow isn't for mentoring and general guidance, it's for people who already know what direction they want to go and need help going there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about connecting it with Python, but I build a support bot using [deadletter.io](https://deadletter.io/learn/tutorials/parcel-chat/) was super fast (once I got my head around their api system)